# BeautifulSoup4 in Sagemath

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, pip, sage

I'm trying to perform web scraping with BS4 and then do some algebra work with the results in Sage 6.2 (in Lion 10.7.5). I assumed that `/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/sage -i beautifulsoup4` would work, but the result is

```
Attempting to download package beautifulsoup4
>>> Checking online list of optional packages.
[Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 35, in <module>
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python/urllib.py", line 240, in retrieve
    fp = self.open(url, data)
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python/urllib.py", line 208, in open
    return getattr(self, name)(url)
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python/urllib.py", line 359, in open_http
    return self.http_error(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python/urllib.py", line 376, in http_error
    return self.http_error_default(url, fp, errcode, errmsg, headers)
  File "<stdin>", line 17, in http_error_default
IOError: [Errno 404] Not Found: '//www.sagemath.org/spkg/optional/list'
Error: failed to download http://www.sagemath.org/spkg/optional/list, aborting
```

Next, I tried `/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/sage -sh <<< "easy_install --verbose pip"` to get bs4 via pip. That succeeded; however `/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/bin/pip2.7 install beautifulsoup4` failed with error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 548, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 530, in main
    known_paths = addusersitepackages(known_paths)
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 266, in addusersitepackages
    user_site = getusersitepackages()
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 241, in getusersitepackages
    user_base = getuserbase() # this will also set USER_BASE
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/site.py", line 231, in getuserbase
    USER_BASE = get_config_var('userbase')
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 516, in get_config_var
    return get_config_vars().get(name)
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py", line 449, in get_config_vars
    import re
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/Applications/Sage-6.2.app/Contents/Resources/sage/local/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT
ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
```

Next, I tried upgrading to Sage 6.6. That went smoothly, as did the installation of bs4. However, when I opened the notebook, I was unable to run code cells, because the "Shift-Enter" command only registered as "Enter" and gave me a new line instead of evaluating the code. Additionally, there was no "evaluate" button. Any recommendations to solve any of these issues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, Sage has changed how it handles optional packages like BS so that older versions may not be able to use them.  You can always go to a mirror, though, like http://mirrors.mit.edu/sage/spkg/optional/ download it, and put it in your (old Sage's) optional spkg directory and try doing `sage -i path/to/file`.

As to the notebook issue, that should be a matter of doing a "hard cache reset" in the browser due to different jQuery versions, see e.g. [here](http://ask.sagemath.org/question/26160/sage-65-notebook-has-no-evaluate-button-after-cells/).

Comment: thanks for the reply. Eventually, I was able to get an alternate solution that got BS4 into Sage 6.2. The terminal command ``sage -sh <<< "pip --verbose install beautifulsoup4"`` did what I wanted.

Comment: Yes, this should definitely work.  I should have mentioned that `sage -pip` is now a working entity.